# Merge [lag] and [latency]

Tags: discussion, tags

The tags [lag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) and [latency](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latency) seem to be about the same thing - network latency. Some of the questions even use the terms interchangeably, for example tagging using one but using the other in the question text. These tags should be synonyms for each other.

However, I'm not sure what the parent tag should be. Anecdotally, latency is used more by technical people, and lag by gamers, so for gamedev it's really a toss-up.

Answer (score 2):

I see some questions that use both to talk about some non-network latency though, one being about input-latency and another about performance (e.g. why does it lag when I render 1 million poly's).

In my opinion I think [latency](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latency) should be about networking and [lag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) be a synonym of it. Questions using [lag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag)/[latency](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latency) for stuff like input latency should be retagged (in the given case just [input](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input)).